# Communicate with an accessory with Wifi bridge capability in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi, adhoc, external-accessory

I am having an external accessory which is capable of generating a wifi bridge i.e it is capable of having its own ad hoc connection. I can connect to the ad-hoc connection from my wifi settings.

What I want is to send data back and forth to this device from my application so that I can configure it to work with my Router's Wifi connection.

Do anybody have the idea how to initiate the communication as there is no public API's available to manage the Wifi connections.

Thanks in advance.